# I can't show an alert and it doesn't take the name variable validation

Tags: javascript, html, regex, events

I'm doing a brief validation of .name but I can't get the alert to show any ideas? I don't know if I'm missing something or if I'm doing something wrong, I appreciate your help

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <title>Proyecto Poker</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action=""  id="form">
        <div class="form">
            <h1>FORMULARIO DE REGISTRO</h1>
            <div class="grupo">
                <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Name" id="nombre"><span class="barra"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="grupo">
                <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Apellido" id="apellido"><span class="barra"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="grupo">
                <input type="number" name="" placeholder="Edad" id="edad"><span class="barra"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="grupo">
                <input type="email" name="" placeholder="Email" id="email"><span class="barra"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="grupo">
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="password"><span class="barra" ></span>   
            </div>
            <button type="submit">Registrarse</button>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script src="./main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

it does not take the validation of the name variable I do not know if I am omitting something or if it is wrong any help is welcome I am just getting started in javascript and I do not have much knowledge thank you very much

JS

```
document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();


    let nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
    let apellido = document.getElementById('apellido').value;
    let edad = document.getElementById('edad').value;
    let email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    let password = document.getElementById('passsword');

    let expRegNombre = /^\s+$/;

    if(nombre == null || nombre.lenght == 0 || expRegNombre.test(nombre)){
        alert('nombre invalido')
    }
})
```

Comment: Typo: `lenght` should be `length`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working as expected. You had a typo where "nombre.lenght == 0" should be nombre.length == 0.

See working snippet below:

```js
document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();


    let nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
    let apellido = document.getElementById('apellido').value;
    let edad = document.getElementById('edad').value;
    let email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    let password = document.getElementById('passsword');

    let expRegNombre = /^\s+$/;

    if(nombre == null || nombre.length == 0 || expRegNombre.test(nombre)){
        alert('nombre invalido')
    }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <title>Proyecto Poker</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action=""  id="form">
        <div class="form">
            <h1>FORMULARIO DE REGISTRO</h1>
            <div class="grupo">
                <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Name" id="nombre"><span class="barra"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="grupo">
                <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Apellido" id="apellido"><span class="barra"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="grupo">
                <input type="number" name="" placeholder="Edad" id="edad"><span class="barra"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="grupo">
                <input type="email" name="" placeholder="Email" id="email"><span class="barra"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="grupo">
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="password"><span class="barra" ></span>   
            </div>
            <button type="submit">Registrarse</button>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script src="./main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```